# Issues frequency in Volume of the journal

Tags: journals, publishers, online-publication, journal-workflow

My doubt is about the number of issues per Volume in a journal and also please let me know about the number of issues of a journal correlates to its indexing frequency in databases. it would be very grateful if you can provide any reference in this regard

I am trying to apply for indexing in Scopus and want to know the criteria to release the regular issues. i.e., distribution of articles among months...

Is it necessary to follow a particular pattern like below

for quarterly,

Mar, June, Sept, Dec OR we can release as Feb, May, Aug, Nov which we can follow?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular issues per volume means?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/125275/regular-issues-per-volume-means)

Comment: You just copied your old and closed question or did I miss an important difference?

Comment: i tried to explain my qs more clearly.. thank you for your patience

Comment: If you tried to add clarity to the question that was closed, then you have failed as you did not change anything significant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of issues per volume is up to you, although it depends greatly on the amount of articles you publish. If you're just starting a new journal I recommend against starting with anything other than 2 issues/year. Having more issues per year runs the major risk of not having enough papers and therefore not being able to publish regularly.

Scopus's regular issue criterion simply means you need to publish your issues when they're supposed to be published. For example if your journal is 4 issues/year but for a few years you've only been publishing 2-3 issues/year, the chances of your journal being delisted increases (or you won't be able to be listed in Scopus in the first place). But it's still up to you to decide how many issues a year your journal will publish.

As for which months quarterly means, it's again up to you, so long as you publish four issues a year.

Comment: Additionally, Scopus has much more critera on journal selection than only the frequency of issues/volumes.